# dietlibc, lowfat, opentracker - compiling against alternative libc

Tags: c, ld, libc

I'm attempting to build [`opentracker`](http://erdgeist.org/arts/software/opentracker/). My system has the following:

```
| package  | library                  | headers               |
| lowfat   | /usr/lib/libowfat.a      | /usr/include/libowfat |
| dietlibc | /opt/diet/lib-x86_64/*.a | /usr/diet/include |
| glibc    | /usr/lib/*.{a,so}        | /usr/include      |
```

Looking at the Makefile for `opentracker`, I see (essentially) the following:

```
PREFIX?=..
LIBOWFAT_HEADERS=$(PREFIX)/libowfat
LIBOWFAT_LIBRARY=$(PREFIX)/libowfat

CFLAGS+=-I$(LIBOWFAT_HEADERS) -Wall -pipe -Wextra 
LDFLAGS+=-L$(LIBOWFAT_LIBRARY) -lowfat -pthread -lpthread -lz

opentrackers: $(OBJECTS) $(HEADERS)
    cc -o $@ $(OBJECTS) $(LDFLAGS)
```

I've not compiled against an alternative `libc` before, so I'm including this information in case I've done this part wrong. When I invoke `make`, I need to point it at where my system has `dietlibc` and `lowfat` live. I'm doing it like this:

```
$ LDFLAGS=-L/opt/diet/lib-x86_64 make PREFIX=/opt/diet LIBOWFAT_HEADERS=/usr/include/libowfat LIBOWFAT_LIBRARY=/usr/lib
...
...
cc -o opentracker opentracker.o trackerlogic.o scan_urlencoded_query.o ot_mutex.o ot_stats.o ot_vector.o ot_clean.o ot_udp.o ot_iovec.o ot_fullscrape.o ot_accesslist.o ot_http.o ot_livesync.o ot_rijndael.o -L/opt/diet/lib-x86_64 -L/usr/lib -lowfat -pthread -lpthread -lz
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib/libowfat.a(io_fd.o):(.bss+0xb0): multiple definition of `first_deferred'; /usr/lib/libowfat.a(io_close.o):(.data+0x0): first defined here
...
... lots of warnings ...
/usr/bin/ld: opentracker.o: undefined reference to symbol '__ctype_b_loc@@GLIBC_2.3'
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib/libc.so.6: error adding symbols: DSO missing from command line
```

Looks like there's two issues going on in there.

---

#### Multiple definitions of `first_deferred`

I see references to `first_deferred` in both `io_close` and `io_fd`, but they are in different sections.

```
$ objdump -t /usr/lib/libowfat.a  | egrep '^[^:]+.o:|first_deferred' | grep -B1 first_deferred

io_close.o:     file format elf64-x86-64
0000000000000000 g     O .data  0000000000000008 first_deferred
--
io_fd.o:     file format elf64-x86-64
00000000000000b0 g     O .bss   0000000000000008 first_deferred
--
io_waituntil2.o:     file format elf64-x86-64
0000000000000000         *UND*  0000000000000000 first_deferred
```

In `io/io_fd.c`, there's an `#include io_internal.h` and in that header there's an `extern long first_deferred;`. In `io/io_close.c` it's defined as `long first_deferred=-1`. So it doesn't look like it's double defined in the `libowfat` code itself. Did I compile `lowfat` wrong?

---

#### DSO missing from command line /  symbol '__ctype_b_loc@@GLIBC_2.3'

Since the `Makefile` is trying to compile against `dietlibc`, I'm a bit surprised that there's a reference to `glibc` (but, to be honest, also not surprised at all).

Here's the recipe for `opentracker.o`:

```
cc -c -o opentracker.o -march=x86-64 -mtune=generic -O2 -pipe -fno-plt -I/usr/include/libowfat -Wall -pipe -Wextra  -O3 -DWANT_FULLSCRAPE opentracker.c
```

This doesn't appear to have the `-L/opt/diet/lib-x86_64` argument from `LDFLAGS` that is used for the main executable. Should it? I don't think so as that's a linker argument so it would not make sense to add it to the compile command. I don't see any references to `glibc` in the object file:

```
$ objdump -t ./src/opentracker/opentracker.o  | grep -c 'glib'
0
```

Answer (score 1):

## DSO missing from command line / symbol '__ctype_b_loc@@GLIBC_2.3'

I found two permutations to solve this issue. Option one is to make sure the very first `-L` argument is the location of `dietlibc`'s lib directory, so that all symbols are resolved from there first.

The other permutation was to invoke make via the `/opt/diet/bin/diet` wrapper program. From [the `dietlibc` FAQ](https://www.fefe.de/dietlibc/FAQ.txt)

```
Q: How do I install it?  make install?
A: Yep.  It will then install itself to /opt/diet, with the wrapper in
   /opt/diet/bin/diet.  Or you don't install it at all.
   The diet libc comes with a wrapper called "diet", which can be found
   in bin-$(ARCH)/diet, i.e.  bin-i386/diet for most of us.  Copy this
   wrapper somewhere in your path (for example ~/bin) and then just
   compile stuff by prepending diet to the command line, e.g. "diet gcc
   -pipe -g -o t t.c".


Q: How do I compile programs using autoconf with the diet libc?
A: Set CC in the environment properly.  For Bourne Shells:

     $ CC="diet gcc -nostdinc" ./configure --disable-nls

   That should be enough, but you might also want to set
   --disable-shared and --enable-static for packages using libtool.
```

It's not explained anywhere on the website, as far as I can tell, what the wrapper program does. The code is annoying to read due to all the architecture specific `#ifdef`s, but the file comment indicates it just modifies the `gcc` command line in an architecture specific way. A quick scan suggests relevant args modifications include: `-I/opt/diet/include` when compiling, `-nostdlib` when linking, and possibly `-Os`.

## Multiple definitions of `first_deferred`

I'm not happy with my workaround here. The symbol is defined in `io_internal.h`:

```
#ifndef my_extern
#define my_extern extern
#endif

my_extern long first_deferred;
```

Why is there a funny redefinition of the `extern` keyword? Read on. The initialization of this variable is in `io_close.c`:

```
#include "io_internal.h"

long first_deferred=-1;
```

And here's the interesting bit. In `io_fd.c`:

```
#define my_extern
#include "io_internal.h"
#undef my_extern
```

Why? Who knows. The author believes they are clever I guess and saved themselves some keystrokes? The effect of this is that `my_extern` is defined as an empty string, so when `my_extern long first_deferred;` is transcluded from the header, it appears as `long first_deferred;`. This is what leads there to be two locations for the symbol in the archive, as there are two files that reserve space for that symbol.

I'm not happy with my "solution", which was to remove the static initialization from `io_close.c`. Technically, that means the variable starts with random heap memory. A quick look at how it gets used suggests this is maybe not safe, but is probably safe enough. The variable is used as an index into an array. Thankfully `iarray_get` does a bounds check, so it's very likely that `if(e)` will be false and the variable will get set to `-1` as it should be.

```
 if (first_deferred!=-1) {
    while (first_deferred!=-1) {
      io_entry* e=iarray_get(&io_fds,first_deferred);
      if (e) {
        if (e->closed) {
          e->closed=0;
          close(first_deferred);
        }
        first_deferred=e->next_defer;
      } else
        first_deferred=-1;      // can't happen
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

I can't provide a good explanation for those errors, but your post helped me to get it to compile so I figured I'd mention what I did.

The "first_deferred" error seems to come from using a newer version of `libowfat`, I got past that by using 0.31 instead.

I didn't come across the second error, but I was getting "__you_tried_to_link_a_dietlibc_object_against_glibc" errors which I got past by uninstalling `dietlibc` and compiling `libowfat` with `glibc` instead.

I compiled them the same way as the AUR packages:

https://aur.archlinux.org/packages/opentracker/

https://aur.archlinux.org/packages/libowfat/

Although, instead of installing `libowfat`, I just put it in the `src` directory and skipped fetching `libowfat` from CVS.